# Can a discrete random variable be both larger and smaller than another?

Tags: probability

Suppose we have two discrete random variables $A$ and $B$ with a finite number of possible outcomes. Then the expression '$A < B$' can be interpreted as a random variable itself, taking the values 'true' and 'false'. Is it possible that

> $P('A<B' = true) > P('A<B' = false)$ and $P('A>B' = true) > P('A>B' = false)$

are true at the same time?

I'm asking because I'm writing a program (as a hobby project of mine) that does arithmetic on discrete random variables. I encountered a result of my program which implies that the above statement is true, however I also suspect there could be a bug in the code...

Answer (score 1):

**Note that $P(A < B = false)$ is just written as $P(A \ge B)$.**

Now, suppose that $P(A < B) > P(A \ge B)$ and $P(A>B) > P(A \le B)$.

We re-write the first inequality as

$$P(A<B) > P(A=B)+P(A > B).$$

Since $P(A=B) \ge 0$, this implies that $P(A<B) > P(A>B)$.

Joint assertion of the inequalities then becomes

$$P(A<B) > P(A \le B).$$

But the $P(A \le B)$ includes every event satisfying $P(A<B)$, so this cannot be true.